Kentico 13 page builder getting config error message
Kentico v13.0.151
Error message showing up on page builder even though page builder seems to be working correctly.

This page does not work properly as your browser may be blocking 3rd
party cookies and/or the system may be incorrectly configured for a
multi-domain environment.
See our documentation for more information.

So the iframe can load in the presentation site and I can work with it fine.
3rd party cookies are allowed.
I've tried all the various cookie settings as per the docs.
The 2 apps are running on separate domains with same site cookies set to none and secure as you can see here


Apply the latest hotfix. There were some issues with partitioned cookies. Then, have you seen this already? https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/troubleshooting-the-page-builder-in-kentico-xperience-13

@jurajo I'm way past that hotfix. I'm on v13.0.151. I read the checklist and there's nothing there. I've edited my answer to include more info

There was some bug fixed in HF152 too. Plus, in the past weeks there were many weird issues caused by wrongly applied hotfix. I would still recommend applying the latest one carefully, following all the instructions from the documentation on applying hotfix. Otherwise, install a stock instance with Dancing Goat and test it to see if the issue is in Kentico or in custom code, environment setup - it can limit possible causes.

@jurajo the hotfix to 154 did it. Many thanks

Just adding here the answer based on the comments - applying the latest hotfix, following the instructions to the degree fixed the issue.
